# How to create model using interface in Angularjs 2 for complex JSON object

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have to create model using interface not by class for complex JSON object.

Please help to remove compilation error. I am trying to extend Address interface in my ICTCompanyDetails interface. But while creating the model in component. it is giving me compilation error.

Interfaces are:

```
import { ICTAddress               } from '../../../generic/address';
    export interface ICTCompanyDetails extends ICTAddress{
    ct_company_id                       :string;
    ct_company_owner_name               :string;
    ct_company_name                     :string;
    ct_company_address                  :ICTAddress[];
    ct_company_email_id                 :string;
    ct_company_mobile_no                :string;
    ct_company_phone_no                 :string;
    ct_company_gst_no                   :string;
    ct_company_pan_no                   :string;
    ct_company_website                  :string;
    ct_company_sac_code                 :string;
    ct_company_logo_name                :string;
    //ct_company_logo                     :File;
    ct_company_digital_sign_stamp_name  :string;
    //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp       :File;
    ct_company_term_condition           :string;
    ct_company_revoke                   :string;
    ct_company_status                   :string;
    ct_company_last_update_datetime     :Date;
    ct_company_last_update_ip           :string;
    ct_company_last_update_login_id     :string;
    }
        export interface ICTAddress{
        ct_address_id   :string;
        ct_address_1    :string;
        ct_address_2    :string;
        ct_address_3    :string;
        ct_country      :string;
        ct_state        :string;
        ct_town_n_city  :string;
        ct_postal_code  :string;
       }

Model is:

company: ICTCompanyDetails = {
        ct_company_id                       : "",
        ct_company_owner_name               : "",
        ct_company_name                     : "",
        ct_company_address                  : ICTAddress [ 
            ct_address_id   :"",
            ct_address_1    :"",
            ct_address_2    :"",
            ct_address_3    :"",
            ct_country      :"",
            ct_state        :"",
            ct_town_n_city  :"",
            ct_postal_code  :"",
        ],
        ct_company_email_id                 : "",
        ct_company_mobile_no                : "",
        ct_company_phone_no                 : "",
        ct_company_gst_no                   : "",
        ct_company_pan_no                   : "",
        ct_company_website                  : "",
        ct_company_sac_code                 : "",
        ct_company_logo_name                : "",
        //ct_company_logo: new File([], ""),
        //ct_company_logo                     :new Blob([], { type: '' }),
        ct_company_digital_sign_stamp_name  : "",
        //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp: new File([], ""),
        //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp       :new Blob([], { type: '' }),
        ct_company_term_condition           : "",
        ct_company_revoke                   : "",
        ct_company_status                   : "",
        ct_company_last_update_datetime     : new Date(),
        ct_company_last_update_ip           : "",
        ct_company_last_update_login_id     : ""
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result when fixed it:

```
ct_company_address                  : [
  { ct_address_id   : '' },
  { ct_address_1    : '' },
  { ct_address_2    : '' },
  { ct_address_3    : '' },
  { ct_country      : '' },
  { ct_state        : '' },
  { ct_town_n_city  : '' },
  { ct_postal_code  : '' }
] as ICTAddress[],
```

full version:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bcjMU9eVcWOnO7tIcqhV?p=preview

Comment: if I am using export for both interfaces in the same component then there is no compilation error. But if i am importing these two interfaces then it is giving me the compilation error stating ct_address_id property is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your component:

```
company: ICTCompanyDetails = {
        ct_company_id                       : "",
        ct_company_owner_name               : "",
        ct_company_name                     : "",
        ct_company_address                  : [ 
            ct_address_id   :"",
            ct_address_1    :"",
            ct_address_2    :"",
            ct_address_3    :"",
            ct_country      :"",
            ct_state        :"",
            ct_town_n_city  :"",
            ct_postal_code  :"",
        ],
        ct_company_email_id                 : "",
        ct_company_mobile_no                : "",
        ct_company_phone_no                 : "",
        ct_company_gst_no                   : "",
        ct_company_pan_no                   : "",
        ct_company_website                  : "",
        ct_company_sac_code                 : "",
        ct_company_logo_name                : "",
        //ct_company_logo: new File([], ""),
        //ct_company_logo                     :new Blob([], { type: '' }),
        ct_company_digital_sign_stamp_name  : "",
        //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp: new File([], ""),
        //ct_company_digital_sign_stamp       :new Blob([], { type: '' }),
        ct_company_term_condition           : "",
        ct_company_revoke                   : "",
        ct_company_status                   : "",
        ct_company_last_update_datetime     : new Date(),
        ct_company_last_update_ip           : "",
        ct_company_last_update_login_id     : ""
    };
```

I just edited ct_company_address.
Hope it will help.